# How can I gather all links on a site without content?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

I would like to get all URLs a site links to (on the same domain) without downloading all of the content with something like wget. Is there a way to tell wget to just list the links it WOULD download?

For a little background of what I'm using this for if someone can come up with a better solution: I'm trying to build a robots.txt file that excludes all files that end with p[4-9].html but robots.txt doesn't support regular expressions. So I'm trying to get all links and then run a regular expression against them then put the result in the robots.txt. Any ideas?

Comment: How can you get the links without getting the content? Would adding `nofollow` to the links help? Example here: http://www.seoconsultants.com/html/links/nofollow

Comment: I know I need to go through the content, but I don't want it saved once it's done looking through it. Unfortunately, I can't add nofollow because most of the site is using a 3rd party app I can't touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation: combine wget and gawk in a (very) small shell script.

There's a good overview of AWK on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK